# Prolog: Downcase all atoms in a list

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a Prolog program that needs to take a user's natural language input and match it against a set of atoms.  I'm using SWI Prolog's `readln/1` to get input and put it in a list of atoms, but I don't have any guarantee of the case of the user input, so I want to just downcase all of the input I get before I try matching.  What I have right now is:

```
downcase_list(AnyCase, LowerCase) :- dcl(AnyCase, X), flatten(X,LowerCase).

dcl([], List) :- List.
dcl([Head|Rest], []) :- downcase_atom(Head,X), dcl(Rest,X).
dcl([Head|Rest], List) :- downcase_atom(Head,X), dcl(Rest, [List|X]).
```

Appending using `[List|X]` seems to be my problem, but I don't know how to fix it, since I've already tried using `append/3` and just got an infinite loop:

```
downcase_list([], List) :- List.
downcase_list([Head|Rest], []) :- downcase_atom(Head,X), downcase_list(Rest, X).
downcase_list([Head|Rest], NewList) :- downcase_atom(Head,X), append(NewList,X,Z), writeln(Z), downcase_list(Rest,Z).
```

I am very new to Prolog (I would classify myself as a Lisp programmer at this point), so it's very possible I'm missing something elementary.  Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have a list of atoms, to downcase them you have to apply a mapping with `maplist/3` and `downcase_atom/2`:

```
downcase_list(AnyCaseList, DownCaseList):-
  maplist(downcase_atom, AnyCaseList, DownCaseList).
```

Comment: wow that was so easy... I hadn't found any use of `maplist` that looked like this.  I thought you had to do `maplist(downcase_atom(AnyCaseList), DownCaseList)`
and it wasn't working, and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: For something like this:
`132 ?- maplist(downcase_atom, [H,E,L,L,O], DownCaseList).` 
I get the following error:
`ERROR: downcase_atom/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

Comment: That is because you are using variables (upper case letters are variables) and not atoms. You should use `?- maplist(downcase_atom, ['H','E','L','L','O'], DownCaseList).`, that is surround every upper case letter with `'`.